# How do I get an entry to re-show up for auto-completion

Tags: microsoft-excel, autocomplete

I have a column of, let's say colors "blue" "yellow" "red" "green". As I'm manually typing in these entries, it makes it easy on me if I can just hit b and blue comes up and I can just hit enter. I don't know what I did but now the entry ("blue) doesn't autocomplete it for me and I'm forced to type it manually. It's an issue since I have hundreds, potentially thousands, more entries to go through. Does anyone know how to reobtain the entry as an autocomplete? ("blue" in this scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have inadvertently typed a little more than the word "blue". Excel offers the auto complete only for cell entries that are a unique match for the letters typed so far. If you have two entries ...

```
`blue`
`blue `  -- note the space after the word
```

... then no auto complete will be offered, because there is more than one match for words that start with b, l, u, e

So, check all the instances of the word and see if there are any rogue characters.

To help find the culprit you can insert a column with a formula that checks the length of the text.

=LEN(A2)

- Copy down.
- Select the column and apply conditional formatting > Color Scales, using the first option.
- filter the data to show only "blue" items. Your data needs to have headers and have the autofilter enabled for this.
- the rogue value will be the one that has a different background color.

Before filtering:

[image]

after filtering

[image]

Edit the rogue value and correct it. Then remove the filter and delete the helper column.

2nd Edit: If that does not lead to the problem cell, the issue may not be with a trailing space but with some other kind of typo and the data is not included in the filtered set.

Create a backup copy. Sort the data by the text column. Inspect the first "blue" value. Inspect the last "blue" value. Use the column next to the text value with a formula that compares the current cell with the cell above.

=IF(A1=A2,"","check")

[image]

Comment: How would you go about and find/fix this error? I have completed hundreds of entries of this and have hundreds (maybe thousands) more to go... Definitely could use some advice on this. Thanks!

Comment: I added some details to the answer.

Comment: I just went through it and they are all of the same length, but thank you for attempting a solution; this definitely might come in handy later on. Do you have any other ideas as to why it stopped showing up as an autocomplete entry? The rest of the entries in the column show up as autocomplete...

Comment: The rogue value may be a typo that does not impact the length and causes the value not to appear in the filtered data. Some more ideas added to the post above.

Comment: That solved it. Although it doesn't really help because the autocomplete only comes up for the last letter. (i.e. if I type in international, the autocomplete will come up after I type in "internationa") Thank you for being so patient and helping me out!

Comment: This may happen if you have values 'international' and 'internationals', to solves this I would put in a space before 'internationals' and when I type a space it picks 'internations' to auto populate first. At the end of my input you can do a find and replace the spaces with blank. Provided there are no spaces in other cells.